How should I handle non-English content in the Staging Ground?
I'm reviewing questions in the staging ground when I find the following question:
https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/79119357
What is the proper thing to do here when reviewing? Flag Options show:

None of these have anything to do with languages other than English. Voting as "off-topic" also doesn't have that as well. Do we "Require Major changes" and move on?

The specific question that you show seems to include both English and non-English text. In many of these cases, the English text is intended by the OP as a translation. If the English text would stand on its own, it's often correct to just edit and remove the non-English text.

That question is written in English! It's only the error message that contains some non-English text. It should be edited into a proper quote. Edit: OK, it was Spanish in the first revision

@Bergi Yeah, when I first reviewed it, it was all in Spanish

If a question is not written in English, it needs to be changed by the author. Therefore, you should write a comment explaining it and use the "Requires Major Changes" option.
For the comment, you can use the "Rewrite non-English content" comment template:

This comment template uses the following content:

Stack Overflow is an [English-only site]. Please try your best to [edit] your question to rewrite it in English.

However, if you can see that the question is intrinsically off-topic or spam, you should use the appropriate option ("Vote as off-topic" for off-topic or flagging spam) for that but if you are not sure, you can always use the "Rewrite non-English content" comment template and the "Requires Major Changes" option. If you can understand the question enough to see any other issues, you can also include that in the comment.

I might sound like a complete doofus, but where did you get that template dialog from? I've never seen it in the SO interface before.

It is only available in the staging ground. When a reviewer goes to leave a comment, there is a template option that will show those templates.

On the main part of the site, users between 15 and 3000 reputation can flag questions, but can't vote to close them. But they are expected to be able to participate in the question closure process, because that's part of overall site curation. Therefore, extra flag reasons are added for questions that cover the close reasons.
But in the Staging Ground, the starting assumptions are different. All the same standards for questions still apply, but functionally the question is already closed - there is only a (threaded) comments section and nowhere to write an answer. The primary purpose of closing a question on the main site is to prevent it from being answered; in the Staging Ground, this has already happened, and the next steps are to a) determine whether the problem could be fixed and b) fix it if possible.
Therefore, the flag options don't cover any reasons for closing a question.
On the other hand, the question doesn't come with a "closed question" banner at the top automatically, because a reason for the closure hasn't been identified yet. (We've simply shifted the default assumption from "this question is probably fine" to "this question probably needs improvement".) So the next step is to figure out what might or might not be wrong with the question.
"The question is not written in English" is a fixable problem, inherently. The OP can, in principle, translate the question; and if there's nothing else wrong with it, then the result is a valid question that should be posted. Since the question is already "closed", we don't need flagging or voting, but we do need to give feedback.
In the staging ground, we give feedback in two ways: a) using the comment section and b) updating the status of the question (this is also necessary to prevent it from being automatically "graduated" later). For problems that are fixable but require the OP's intervention, please use "Major Changes" status. As for the feedback, we have a template comment for that, as shown in dan1st's answer.

I disagree with the portrayal that SG questions are "already closed". it takes one particular individual to click "LGTM" in order for the question to be set free immediately, and if nobody reacts, it's automatically released after a day anyway. at least, that's what I've been led to believe.

@ChristophRackwitz as I understood it, the "automatic release after a day" is for questions marked for Minor Edits. Other questions may be graduated automatically if completely ignored, but with a longer delay AFAIK. At any rate, the question is "closed" in the sense that the purpose of closure is in effect; it's just a weaker form of closure.
